# fgets, C, чтение файла дважды

Tags: c

возникла проблема , что после прочтения файла с помощью функции fgets достигаю  EOF ,и при повторении цикла , второй раз не работает. Как передвинуть указатель на начало файла , или файл закрыть и открыть снова ?

```
while (fgets(str,254,out)!=NULL)
        {
           printf("%s",str);
        }
 while (fgets(str,254,out)!=NULL)
        {
           printf("%s",str);
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перемотать поток на начало можно с помощью

```
fseek (out, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

или

```
rewind (out);
```